# Finding name of column(s) based on a value stored MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have recently joined a company as a junior developer. I am expected to pull data from relevant tables/columns in MYSQL and have no idea where to look.

Is there a way I can find the list of columns in their respected tables based on a value I know the column would have? E.g searching the entire database for the value 'bob' to determine the name of the column? (in this case the name of the column could be 'first_name' associated with the 'users' table OR 'Employee' table).

Comment: You want to scan every table/column to find columns that contain a specific value so you can go back and query those columns? This sounds like a terrible idea...

Comment: How else can i find the name of a column based on a value that i know it contains?